# Save File method in Java class or Android activity?

Tags: java, android, internal-storage

I've got an app that will take the user's score, save it to the current list of scores, and then display all the scores. The saveScores method is in the HighScores class, but will be called from the Activity in which the user enters their name.

Because the method is in a java class and not an Android activity, I'm having trouble getting the code to work. I've tried two options and each gives a different error:

Option 1:

```
FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("highScores.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//ERROR: The method openFileOutput(String, int) is undefined for the type HighScore.
```

Option 2:

```
FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("highScores.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
//ERROR: MODE_PRIVATE cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Option 1 is exactly the code from the [tutorial](http://www.androidinterview.com/android-internal-storage-read-and-write-text-file-example/) I used, which worked when I ran it, so should be the correct option. But since there's no context in the java class, I think that's where it's having trouble. **Is there any way to make this work other than moving this whole method to the activity?**

For what it's worth, here's the whole saveFile method:

```
public void saveScores(Context context, ArrayList<Score> scores){
    // save to file
    try{
        String allScores ="";
        FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("highScores.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);    // The line in question.
        OutputStreamWriter outputWriter=new OutputStreamWriter(fileout);

        for (int i=0; i<scores.size(); i++)
            allScores += ((i+1)+". "+scores.get(i).toString()+"\n");

        outputWriter.write(allScores);
        outputWriter.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
         System.out.println("SaveScores ERROR: File Not Found.");
    }catch(IOException e){
         System.out.println("SaveScores ERROR: See Stack Trace below.");
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Those are not methods but statements. You need to post the declaration of your method (function). And indeed: add a context to the parameters of your function.

Comment: I know, that's just the line that's giving me trouble. I actually just updated to post the whole method.

Comment: Good. So use `context.openFileOutput`.`

Comment: in Android its also really easy to save stuff like that in a SQLite db, if you're into that kinda thing....

Comment: @greenapps That did it, thank you! If you'd like to post it as an answer I'll select it.

Comment: @BartHofma This is just going to be a text file of ten int scores and user names, so I don't think it needs a db. Thanks, though!

Comment: it's small and fast and secure, i use it to hold 1 record with logindata in my app ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `context.openFileOutput.`

But also give saveScores() a boolean return value. Return false if there is a catch. If you call it then check return value.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("highScores.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Should be using:

```
FileOutputStream fileout=context.openFileOutput("highScores.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

You're getting:

```
FileOutputStream fileout=openFileOutput("highScores.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
//ERROR: The method openFileOutput(String, int) is undefined for the type HighScore.
```

because its looking for `openFileOutput` method within your HighScore class, which it will never find, because you don't have/need one, due to it being part of the `Context`.